# Use @Ignore in AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, unit-testing, annotations

I'm working my way through some unit testing with AndroidTestCase and was wondering, if it's possible to use the ignore-annotation, that I've read about for junit4? Just using the annotation gives an error, maybe, there's something special to look out for?

Thanx in advance,
Marcus

Comment: You can use `@Suppress` on the test case class or on individual "testSomeName" methods.

Comment: right, nice. make that an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: Yep, as long as you're not doing something weird in an implementation of `InstrumentationTestRunner` also it will not test the annotated methods or classes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `@Suppress` on the test case class or individual test methods to suppress test execution.

Comment: Only `@Ignore` works for me now - `@Suppress` has no effect

Comment: import androidx.test.filters.Suppress

Answer (score 2):

You can now use either `@Suppress` or `@Ignore` when running with `AndroidJUnit4`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Ignore` is meant to be temporarily disabled and the output shows the number of tests skipped. It also provides a parameter for the reason it's ignored.

`@Suppress` is meant to be excluded and does not show the number of tests skipped.

Each is useful, but it depends what you're using it for.  Our team slightly prefers `@Suppress` because they don't want to see the number skipped in the output. You can add a comment next to the Suppress annotation to document why it's suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Android ships with JUnit3 - and the ignore-annotation is part of JUnit4.  Check [this](https://github.com/dthommes/JUnit4Android/wiki) project out on GitHub, it might work for you.