# What to do to ignore test case in Android?

Tags: android, android-testing

Hi i just worked on roblectric test cases where we can use `@Ignore` to ignore the test cases My question is what we can do in case of android unit test cases for AndroidTestCase instrumentation project, is  `@Suppress` of android test cases is same as Robolectric `@Igore`? please give me some information, already i visited

[Use @Ignore in AndroidTestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600127/use-ignore-in-androidtestcase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AndroidTestCase is kind of JUnit3 which doesn't have analog of JUnit4 @Ignore. The simplest workaround is rename your testXXX() method to ignoreXXX(). This should help because JUnit 3 runs only method with 'test' prefix.

Comment: I think it is better in that case to comment out the entire code instead of renaming the method. Too easy to miss what is going on for a new dev, especially if they are coming from Junit4...

Answer (score 7):

You can use @Suppress on the test case class or individual test methods to suppress test execution.

Answer (score 2):

In 2017, In addition to @santos's answer You can just remove the @Test annotation to ignore the function to test.